# gunicorn.errors.HaltServer while deploying to google cloud run for a python application

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, google-cloud-run

Here is my dockerfile. I am trying to deploy this image to google cloud run using below two command

```
1. gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/smartshop-292203/data_science --timeout=20h0m0s
2. gcloud run deploy --image gcr.io/smartshop-292203/data_science --platform managed
```

I am using this reference link

```
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#python
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# update image and install cmake
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install cmake -y
RUN apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx -y

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# command to run on container start
# CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ] 
# CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :8001 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 1500 main:app
# CMD exec gunicorn main:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --worker-class aiohttp.GunicornWebWorker
# CMD exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi:main
# CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Errors i am getting:

```
        "Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
        sys.exit(run())
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
        WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
        super().run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
        Arbiter(self).run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 227, in run
        self.halt()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
        self.stop()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
        time.sleep(0.1)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
        self.reap_workers()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
        raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
    gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>"
```

What will be the issue ?
Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `gunicorn` with `--preload`. You will see the full stack trace. Seems like something wrong on app creation step.

Also you can deploy you app using:
`gcloud beta run deploy - deploy`

More info https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find what causes these errors from your error messages so check **"LOGS"** on **Cloud Run** as shown below so that you can find more information and details about what causes these errors.

[image]